# ffmpeg how to determine the size of the image and stretch the video to fit it?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to automatically detect the size of the image and stretch the video to fit it.
I have images of different sizes.
There is a video with a green background one size.
I remove the chromakey and overlay the image.
But I have a problem, my video is of a different size.
Me need to automatically expand or contract it to the size of the image.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color a
set a=Your_files\*.jpg
set aa=Your_files\*.mp4
set b="Result\%%~na.mp4"
set c=ffmpeg
set f=-filter_complex "[1:v]chromakey=0x00D700:0.1:0.3[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay=(W-w)/1:(H-h)/1[o]" -map [o] -map 1:a -c:a copy
for %%s in (%aa%) do !set aud="%%s"!
for %%a in (%a%) do (%c% -y -i "%%a" -i %aud% %f% %b%)
exit
```

Help me please

Bad idea.. Images can be of different formats. (there will be distortion)

> Me only one thing comes to my mind.
> Separately resize the image.
> Separately resize the video.
> And then work with them...

Comment: See the [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.
Here i fitting the video to the image size
Then you can work with this video as needed..

```
@echo off
color a
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=Result\*.mp4
set aa=Your_files\*.jpg
set b="Result\temp1.mp4"
set c=ffmpeg
set f=-filter_complex "scale2ref[2nd][ref];[ref][2nd]overlay" -preset ultrafast -codec:a copy
for %%s in (%aa%) do !set aud="%%s"!
for %%a in (%a%) do (%c% -y -i "%%a" -i %aud% %f% %b%)
exit
```

I am working on creating ready-made archives for ffmpeg, you can see them here
[FFMPEG_BAT for Windows OS](https://github.com/brendan8c/FFMPEG_BAT)